# Gmail reply-to field for one message

Tags: gmail

Is there a way to send a message with a *Reply-to* field without changing the whole mailbox settings?

I did such thing with an application, but I’m puzzled about the web interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not with the Web interface, no. You *might* be able to do it with a third-party app, like Thunderbird.